# Not able to override extensions function in another extension - Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to convert code from Swift 3 to Swift 4:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView: Localizable {
    public func localize() {
        subviews.forEach { $0.localize() }
    }
}

public extension UILabel {
    public override func localize() {
        super.localize()
        localize(text) { text = $0 }
    }
}
```

What can be the solution to get this code running with similar logic on Swift 4 ?

Comment: Your code isn't valid in any version of Swift. Extensions can't override. See the [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: You may also wish to scan [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+extension+override).

Comment: @rmaddy It would've been valid in Swift 3 due to implicit `@objc` inference (and implicit `dynamic` inference for `@objc` extension methods which still exists in Swift 4). This would've permitted the override as it would use Obj-C message dispatch. OP can fix the problem by marking the `localize` method in `extension UIView` `@objc` (whether or not it's actually a good idea to do this or not is another matter). Pretty sure there's a dupe for this somewhere.